# In authoritarian countries, is it more effective for protesters to make economic demands or political demands?

Tags: democracy, protests, authoritarianism

**Context:**

I was involved in a discussion about the rationality of protesters in Russia. The thesis was that, given that the regime is very reluctant to give up its political control over the country, but at the same time it is quite OK with making some economic reforms, reducing governmental control over the economy and even fighting some low-level corruption, it would be more effective for protesters to make *economic* demands instead of *political* ones (or at least do not make the latter the main ones). Moreover, authoritarian regimes often react to demands for more political freedom in the completely opposite way, that is, by limiting it.

**More formal formulation of my question**

Although I would appreciate a broad answer too, it seems that the efficient strategy of protesters largely depends on the conditions. So, to narrow the question a bit, I would formulate my question as following:

***What is the most efficient strategy for protesters in terms of demands they make, given that:***

- The political regime in their country has the following priorities in order:

  1. Preserving their comfort and their control of power (most important)
  2. National greatness
  3. The well-being of citizens (least important, but not completely unimportant)
- The economy is big enough that the highest elite (say, <100 men) can have very high standards of living without significantly lowering standards of living of others, but if all officials are corrupt, the damage is very significant
- There are limited but non-zero political freedoms and a formally democratic system
- The regime is assumed to be rational
- The regime is stable

*(I've provided these conditions to exclude extreme cases like rich Middle East monarchies where everyone can be happy or China where it is impossible to protest, although if you have something interesting to say about them, feel free to do so. If you on the contrary need even more narrower context to answer the question, you might use Russian regime as an example.*

Comment: I think, USAID sources may help you: https://www.usaid.gov/democracy - they are usually supporting other countries collaborants. In fact any opposition force for the country you want to destabilize may help you in your efforts.

Comment: If regime is rational then it should never give in to protesters. If you follow the dictators handbook then you have an elite that support you, and the rest should be ignored. If dictators start to bend to protesters then it will only mean more problems for them.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle that's quite debatable. Given that a protest may grow into a revolution if the protesters are completely ignored, it might be a better strategy to give in a bit so that to calm down the nation

Comment: @kandi I agree it is debatable, that is also why I didn't put is as an answer. But the book: The dictators handbook argues for how you should run a government, and it is sort of serious.

Comment: @kandi The problem is that giving too much in a dictatorship gives the protestors the idea that they have the power to make demands and can weaken the dictatorship. Since many dictatorships are powered by cults of personality based on the dictator looking strong, it is better to ignore those not part of said cult or make any concession to protestors incredibly small to not look 'weak'